# How to exclude creation of css chunk files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, css-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have a project in which I have to build all the modules into one file, and also split it into modules.
But I don't need css files for modules except for one common.

My files:

file 'a.js'

```
import 'a.css';
import b from 'b.js';
import c from 'c.js';

// some code
```

file 'b.js'

```
import 'b.css';
import d from 'd.js';

// some code
```

file 'c.js'

```
import 'c.css';
import e from 'e.js';

// some code
```

file 'd.js'

```
import 'd.css';

// some code
```

file 'e.js'

```
import 'e.css';

// some code
```

my 'webpack.config.js'

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/a.js',
        
        c: {
            import: './src/c.js',
        },
        
        b: {
            import: './src/b.js',
        },

        a: {
            import: './src/a.js',
            dependOn: ['b', 'c']
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: (pathData) => {
            if (pathData.chunk.name === 'main') {
                return '[name].js';
            }

            return 'modules/[name].js';
        },
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== 'main'
        }
    },

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: ['autoprefixer']
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                outputStyle: 'expanded'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: (pathData) => {
                return pathData.chunk.name === 'main' ? 'main.css' : 'modules/[name].css';
            },
        })
    ]
};
```

my 'dist' directory

```
dist:
    main.js
    main.css
    modules:
        a.js
        a.css
        b.js
        b.css
        c.js
        c.css
```

I want MiniCssExtractPlugin does not create 'modules/a.css', 'modules/b.css', 'modules/c.css' files

```
dist:
    main.js
    main.css
    modules:
        a.js
        b.js
        c.js
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Extracting all CSS in a single file](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-all-css-in-a-single-file)

> The CSS can be extracted in one CSS file using `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups`.

E.g.

project structure:

```
$ tree -L 3 -I node_modules
.
├── dist
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── main.js
│   └── modules
│       ├── a.js
│       ├── b.js
│       └── c.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── a.css
│   ├── a.js
│   ├── b.css
│   ├── b.js
│   ├── c.css
│   ├── c.js
│   ├── d.css
│   ├── d.js
│   ├── e.css
│   └── e.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

**Note**: The module path should start with `./`, like `./a.css` and `./b.js`. If you import the module like this `import b from 'b'`, `'b'` will be treated as a module request and resolve within module directories (`node_modules`)

Rule 1.

> Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'

Rule 2.

> Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (`node_modules`)

`src/a.js`:

```js
import 'a.css';
import b from './b.js';
import c from './c.js';
```

`src/b.js`:

```js
import './b.css';
import d from './d.js';

export default 'b';
```

`src/c.js`:

```js
import './c.css';
import e from './e.js';

export default 'c';
```

`src/d.js`:

```js
import './d.css';
export default 'd';
```

`src/e.js`:

```js
import './e.css';

export default 'e';
```

`src/a.css`:

```css
.a {
    color: aqua;
}
```

`src/b.css`:

```css
.b {
    color: bisque;
}
```

`src/c.css`:

```css
.c {
    color: cadetblue;
}
```

`src/d.css`:

```css
.d {
    color: yellow;
}
```

`src/e.css`:

```css
.e {
    color: slateblue;
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: './src/a.js',
        c: {
            import: './src/c.js',
        },

        b: {
            import: './src/b.js',
        },

        a: {
            import: './src/a.js',
            dependOn: ['b', 'c'],
        },
    },
    output: {
        filename: (pathData) => {
            if (pathData.chunk.name === 'main') {
                return '[name].js';
            }
            return 'modules/[name].js';
        },
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: (chunk) => chunk.name !== 'main',
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: {
                    name: 'styles',
                    type: 'css/mini-extract',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'main.css' })],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

assets by path modules/*.js 1.98 KiB
  asset modules/b.js 946 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: b)
  asset modules/c.js 946 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: c)
  asset modules/a.js 134 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: a)
asset main.js 950 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
asset main.css 124 bytes [compared for emit] (name: styles) (id hint: styles)
Entrypoint main 1.05 KiB = main.css 124 bytes main.js 950 bytes
Entrypoint c 1.04 KiB = main.css 124 bytes modules/c.js 946 bytes
Entrypoint b 1.04 KiB = main.css 124 bytes modules/b.js 946 bytes
Entrypoint a 258 bytes = main.css 124 bytes modules/a.js 134 bytes
orphan modules 4.83 KiB (javascript) 4.58 KiB (runtime) [orphan] 34 modules
runtime modules 7.39 KiB 9 modules
cacheable modules 119 bytes (css/mini-extract) 192 bytes (javascript)
  modules by path ./src/*.css 119 bytes
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/a.css 21 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/b.css 23 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/c.css 26 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/d.css 23 bytes [built] [code generated]
    css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/e.css 26 bytes [built] [code generated]
  javascript modules 192 bytes
    ./src/a.js 66 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/c.js 63 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/b.js 63 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 301 ms
```

Output

`dist/main.css`:

```css
.a {
    color: aqua;
}

.b {
    color: bisque;
}

.d {
    color: yellow;
}

.c {
    color: cadetblue;
}

.e {
    color: slateblue;
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```